# Как убрать символы из строки, которая вернулась из базы данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, строки, обработка-данных

Строка возвращается из базы данных в таком формате:

```py
('text',)
```

Как это дело обрезать и оставить только `text`?

Comment: оставить только text?

Comment: @Jack_oS Так точно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При чтении данных из БД с использованием методов `cursor.fetchone()`, `cursor.fetchall()` - вы всегда получаете кортежи с данными, в не зависимости от того сколько столбцов таблицы вы читаете - один или несколько.

Судя по тому, что вы получаете строку `"('text',)"` вместо кортежа `('text',)`, вы неправильно обрабатываете полученные из БД кортежи с данными. А именно применяете `str()` к полученному из БД кортежу данных:

Пример того, как делать **не нужно**:

```
cur.execute("SELECT text_col FROM table_name")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    text = str(row)  # <-- опасное и ненужное преобразование кортежа с данными в строку!
    print(text)
```

так делать не стоит сразу по нескольким причинам - вы превращаете кортеж с упорядоченными данными (с правильными типами данных) в строку, которую впоследствии придется парсить и, в случае когда столбец(цы) таблицы имеют нестроковой тип данных, еще и преобразовывать эти элементы обратно к правильным типам данных. Это ненужные операции, замедляющие код и делающие его менее понятным.

Лучше сделать так:

```
cur.execute("SELECT text_col FROM table_name")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    text = row[0]
    # дальше мы используем text
```

Answer (score 4):

вот так:

```
x = ('text', )
x = x[0]
```

если это строка, то так:

```
x = "('text',)"
x = x[2:-3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте встроенный метод для строк [str.replace(old, new[, count])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```py
my_str = "('text',)"
plain_str = my_str.replace("('", "").replace("',)", "")
```

заменит ненужные подстроки на пустые, в результате:

```py
>>> plain_str
text
```

Comment: в первом replace мне кажется должен быть `('` а не `(`

Comment: @Danis вам не кажется, мой косяк... исправил, спасибо!

Comment: @Jack_oS return "Thank You";

Comment: @CatException `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`:)

Comment: @Danis ну у нас тут другой синтаксис :)